# Can show pdf in some columns in jtable as link to download?

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jtable

Can I show a PDF in a column of a `JTable` as link to download!?  Is that possible 
cause I've searched on Google but can't find anything,

Actually I have table in database named `projet(id,nomprojet,date,cout,rapportpdf,pdf)`. Some projet have a rapport some else no, so i have the project ligne in `JTable`

Can i have column as link to save rapportpdf on Desktop,

Comment: Yes, yes you can.  Start by having a look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one approach would be to have the column containing the link to be rendered as a button. See [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). Then when the user clicks on the button you can display the pdf.

If you want the column to look like a regular hyperlink, then you would need to create a custom renderer so it display like a link and a custom editor to invoke the action when you click on it. MadProgrammer has given you the link to the tutorial which explains renderers and editors in more detail.