# render and edit a JButton to carrying a link in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

i want to add a column in my Jtable that allow users to save a file pdf on desktop 
i do search on google and i find that i can use, 'custom CellRenderer java' and 'custom CellEditor java'  and render and edit with a JButton to carrying a link.But i can't find the way to start, and how ca i do it

i have this methode that display i jTbale successfully

```
public void ListeAlll(){

    DefaultTableModel tabla = new DefaultTableModel();
    Activiter ac = new Activiter();
    ArrayList<Activiter> lista2 = new ArrayList();
    lista2 = ac.ListeAll();
    tabla.addColumn("Nom");
    tabla.addColumn("Prenom");
    ....
    ....
    tabla.setRowCount(lista2.size());

    int i=0;
    for (Activiter x : lista2){

        tabla.setValueAt(x.getnom(), i, 0);
        tabla.setValueAt(x.getprenom(), i, 1);
        ...

        i++;
      // 
}
    this.jTable2.setModel(tabla);

}
```

please help and thanks

Comment: What do you mean you don't know where to start? I gave you this exact answer in your earlier posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147280/can-show-pdf-in-some-columns-in-jtable-as-link-to-download. It gets extremely annoying when you waste the time of people in the forum because you don't read the answers in your posting. 17 people have wasted time reading this question even though the answer was given yesterday.

Comment: thanks for help, and am sorry, it's resolved  by answer's @Guillaume Polet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use the [`ButtonColumn`](http://www.camick.com/java/source/ButtonColumn.java) class of Rob Camick: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/

The basic idea is indeed to have both renderer and editor for that column to be a `JButton`

It works very nicely and is really easy to use. It does not rely on external libraries.

Comment: @Zero-dev It is actually quite simple: `new ButtonColumn(table, action, column)` where `table` is the  `JTable` on which you want to display thie button column, `action` is an implementation of `Action` (usually, you can simply extends `AbstractAction`) that will perform something when a button is clicked (use `int modelRow = Integer.valueOf( e.getActionCommand() );` to retrieve the clicked row), and `column` is an `int` which indicates the index of that column in the table. The constructor will do everything for you and you should be good to go.